# Applying multiple filters and sorting on api response in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Following api response receiving to me:

```
[
    {
      "imgPaths":[
         "gallery/products/55ccb60cddb4d9bded02accb26827ce4"
      ],
      "_id":"5f3e961d65c6d591ba04f3d3",
      "productName":" Jiva Ayurveda Honey (500g) ",
      "categoryId":{
         "_id":"5f2139322d46a455487b2ea6",
         "categoryName":"Nutrition and supplements",
         "imgPath":"gallery/category/c20ae1717899fad2a6ff3f3ceab381ff"
      },
      "manufacturer":"Jiva",
      "basePrice":"190",
      "finalPrice":"187",
      "availability":"in-stock",
      "createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:26:21.092Z"
   },
   {
      "imgPaths":[
         "gallery/products/72b0e1cf078f26ed0ec0280c1cf8865d"
      ],
      "_id":"5f3e962465c6d591ba04f3d4",
      "productName":"Baidyanath Keshrikalp Royal Chyawanprash (500g) ",
      "categoryId":{
         "_id":"5f2139322d46a455487b2ea6",
         "categoryName":"Nutrition and supplements",
         "imgPath":"gallery/category/c20ae1717899fad2a6ff3f3ceab381ff"
      },
      "manufacturer":"Baidyanath",
      "basePrice":"394",
      "finalPrice":"378",
      "availability":"in-stock",
      "createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:26:28.103Z"
   }
]
```

and i want to perform the filters for 'manufacturer' and 'finalPrice' and different sorting like 'high to low', 'low to high' and 'recently added' and for that all i have write down following
methods :

1. For sorting i do like as below :

```js
    onSortChange(event) {
        //why not lodash used : accepting values are in string formats
        if(event.value==="Lowtohigh"){
          this.productsbycategory.sort((a, b) => {
                return Number(a.finalPrice) - Number(b.finalPrice); 
           })
          }
          else if(event.value==="hightolow"){
            this.productsbycategory.sort((a, b) => {
              return Number(b.finalPrice) - Number(a.finalPrice);
            })
           }
          else if(event.value==="recentlyadded"){
            this.productsbycategory.sort((a, b) => {
              return +new Date(b.createdAt) - +new Date(a .createdAt);
            })
        }
    }
```

2. For filtering manufacturer i write method as below :

onBrandFilterChange(event) {

```
  if(event.target.checked===true && !numbers.includes(event.target.value)){
    numbers.push(event.target.value);
    this.productsbycategory= _.filter(this.filteredProducts, function(p){
      return _.includes(numbers, p.manufacturer);
    });
  }
  else if(event.target.checked===false && numbers.includes(event.target.value)){
    _.pull(numbers,event.target.value);
    if(numbers.length>0){
    this.productsbycategory= _.filter(this.filteredProducts, function(p){
      return _.includes(numbers, p.manufacturer);
    });
    }
    else{
        this.setData();
    }
  }
}
```

3. for Filtering price i write method as below :

```
onPriceFilterChange(min, max) {
    console.log(min, max);
    if (min >= 1 && max <= 5000) {
      this.productsbycategory = this.productsbycategory.filter(function (elem) {
        return Number(elem.finalPrice) >= min && Number(elem.finalPrice) <= max;
      });
    } else {
      alert('Please select valid range');
    }
  }
```

---

I want to modified above code such that we can performs the all filters and sorting at a time.
}

Comment: can you explain what is meant by `performs the all filters and sorting at a time` ?

Comment: multiple filters should works.

Comment: how it should work ? you mean if someone changes any criteria , it should be applied to filtered content instead of all the data ?

Comment: not like that,  let me explain you in details.

Comment: I have check boxes for manufacturer filter and range slider for price filter and dropdown for sorting high to low and low to high.

Comment: when i did filter for manufacturer, i want to filter price wise and and also do sorting on it.

Comment: exactly like this page :https://www.healthmug.com/products/homeopathy/1

Comment: create stackblitz with the code you have tried so far : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xzzu5h?file=src/app/app.component.ts and share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this approach. Read comments in code, test it by pressing 'Run code snippet' button

```js
// Your data
data = [
    {
      "imgPaths":[
         "gallery/products/55ccb60cddb4d9bded02accb26827ce4"
      ],
      "_id":"5f3e961d65c6d591ba04f3d3",
      "productName":" Jiva Ayurveda Honey (500g) ",
      "categoryId":{
         "_id":"5f2139322d46a455487b2ea6",
         "categoryName":"Nutrition and supplements",
         "imgPath":"gallery/category/c20ae1717899fad2a6ff3f3ceab381ff"
      },
      "manufacturer":"Jiva",
      "basePrice":"190",
      "finalPrice":"187",
      "availability":"in-stock",
      "createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:26:21.092Z"
   },
   {
      "imgPaths":[
         "gallery/products/72b0e1cf078f26ed0ec0280c1cf8865d"
      ],
      "_id":"5f3e962465c6d591ba04f3d4",
      "productName":"Baidyanath Keshrikalp Royal Chyawanprash (500g) ",
      "categoryId":{
         "_id":"5f2139322d46a455487b2ea6",
         "categoryName":"Nutrition and supplements",
         "imgPath":"gallery/category/c20ae1717899fad2a6ff3f3ceab381ff"
      },
      "manufacturer":"Baidyanath",
      "basePrice":"394",
      "finalPrice":"378",
      "availability":"in-stock",
      "createdAt":"2020-08-20T15:26:28.103Z"
   }
];

// Price filter function
// Provide data array, min and max price
const priceFilter = (data, min, max) => data.filter((item) => item.finalPrice >= min && item.finalPrice <= max);

// Manufacture filter function
// Provide name
const manFilter = (data, man) => data.filter((item) => item.manufacturer.toLowerCase() === man.toLowerCase());

// Sort data array by some parameters
// Provide data array and options object:
// desc:true for descending sort (ascending
// by default), price:true to sort by price
// or date:true to sort by date.
const customSort = (data, { desc, price, date }) => data.sort((a, b) => {
  if(desc) { const c = a; a = b; b = c; }
  if(price) return a.finalPrice - b.finalPrice;
  else if(date) return new Date(a.createdAt) - new Date(b.createdAt);
});

// Test

// Descending sort by date
console.log('Sort test: ', customSort(data, { desc: true, date: true }));

// Filter by price
console.log('Filter by price test: ', priceFilter(data, 200, 400));

// Filter by name (case insensetive)
console.log('Filter by name test: ', manFilter(data, 'JIVA'));
```

If you want to apply multiple filters one by one, then it's easy as this

```
// data = [ ... your data here ... ];

// First filter your data by manufacturer
data = manFilter(data, 'Baidyanath');

// Now take previously filtered data
// and filter again by price limits
data = priceFilter(data, 100, 300);

// Now take previously filtered data
// by manufacturer and price limits
// and do ascending sort by price field
data = customSort(data, { price: true });

// Now your data is filtered and sorted
// Continue to your program logic
return data;
```

Comment: i want to multiple filters.

Comment: @rahuljadhav well it is doing multiple filtering - look at the end of my post, there is an example how you could chain your data through different filters. And if you need to create new filter, i.e for `availability`, then just add new function with proper field as in my example, then chain this filter with others.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the data based on the requirement like:

recentlyadded:

```
data.filter(item=>new Date(item.createdAt)).reverse()
```

And for Lowtohigh to Hightolow:

```
data.filter(item=>Number(item.finalPrice)).sort()
data.filter(item=>Number(item.finalPrice)).reverse()
```

Thanks